# Asterisk Realtime User Registration

Tags: mysql, real-time, asterisk, user-data

I am using **Asterisk Realtime** architecture.

I try to dynamically and automatically register user data on my mysql. But i can't set the user info on mysql db.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting an error message when you write to the table?
Are you writing to the table OK, but Asterisk isn't picking up your changes?
Is Asterisk picking up your changes, but the phones can't connect?

Your question is lacking enough detail to really help you out.  I'd encourage providing logs, or screen shots, or at least a detailed summary of what you have working so far.

Answer (score 0):

It is not fully clear what is your issue, but i think this article will solve it

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime+Sip